# Historical table with start and end dates and pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, date, pivot, common-table-expression

I have a historical table.

Conditions:

`min` date from date_asgn to start the start_cycle
end cycle second before the next date. 
Only need the latest date for that day, doesn't matter which role it's under.

```
PKID    ID   CUSTID  ROLE      Date_ASGN
 1      45    4565   Primary   12/20/2018 3:12:24 PM
 2      45    4025   Secondary 12/20/2018 3:12:24 PM
 3      45    594    Primary   1/2/2019 4:09:58 PM
```

My expected output:

```
ID START_CYCLE          END_CYCLE          PRIMARY  SECONDARY  BACKUP
45  12/20/2018 3:12:24  1/2/2019 4:09:57   4565       4025      NULL
45  1/2/2019   4:09:58  12/31/9999         594        4025      NULL
```

My current SQL.

```
SELECT
A.ID,
A.DATE_ASGN AS START_CYCLE,
CASE WHEN LEAD (A.DATE_ASGN ) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY A.DATE_ASGN ) = TRUNC(A.DATE_ASGN ) THEN NULL 
ELSE LEAD (A.DATE_ASGN ) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY A.DATE_ASGN ) - NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'second')
END AS END_CYCLE,
'' AS [PRIMARY],
'' AS SECONDARY
'' AS [BACKUP]

FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT H.*,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,TRUNC(H.DATE_ASGN) ORDER BY H.DATE_ASGN DESC,PK DESC) RNK
  FROM  H
  WHERE H.ID = 45
                          )
                          WHERE RNK = 1) A
```

Output:

```
 ID  START_CYCLE            END_CYCLE           PRIMARY  SECONDARY  BACKUP
 45   12/20/2018 3:12:24 PM 1/2/2019 4:09:57 PM  
 45   1/2/2019 4:09:58      12/31/9999
```

What other steps need to occur to get my expected output. I was thinking about turning my SQL into a CTE and working from there but not sure where to begin.

Comment: What if there were two secondary roles between the start and end dates? Or, what if the last row was a secondary role? What's the rule behind what gets put in the primary and secondary columns?

Comment: @Boneist - the way I read this, if there are three (or four, etc.) distinct values in the `DATE_ASGN` column, there will be three (or four, etc.) values in the output. I see the input data as a history of assignments, and the output as a more complete report of who was assigned to what over the different time periods. (Obviously, that is what the solution in my Answer does.) The only ambiguity is if there are duplicates in `(ID, ROLE, DATE_ASGN)` - I silently assumed there's a unique constraint on that combination.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the elements of a solution. So you shouldn't have much trouble understanding the code below. Please do ask follow-up questions as needed though.

Notice the intermediate step, the CTE I called `p` - we need to get rid of unneeded columns when we use the `pivot` operator (in this case, column `PKID`), and I put your additional filter, `where id = 45`, in this intermediate step.

```
with
  h (pkid, id, custid, role, date_asgn) as (
    select 1, 45,  4565, 'Primary'  , to_date('12/20/2018 3:12:24 PM'
                                , 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') from dual union all
    select 2, 45,  4025, 'Secondary', to_date('12/20/2018 3:12:24 PM'
                                , 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') from dual union all
    select 3, 45,   594, 'Primary'  , to_date('1/2/2019 4:09:58 PM  '
                                , 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') from dual
  )
, p as (select id, custid, role, date_asgn from h where id = 45)
select id, date_asgn as start_cycle,
       lead(date_asgn, 1, date '9999-12-31') over (order by date_asgn) end_cycle,
       last_value(primary   ignore nulls)    over (order by date_asgn) primary,
       last_value(secondary ignore nulls)    over (order by date_asgn) secondary,
       last_value(backup    ignore nulls)    over (order by date_asgn) backup
from   p
pivot  (max(custid) for role in ('Primary' primary, 'Secondary' secondary,
                                                       'Backup' backup))
;

ID START_CYCLE            END_CYCLE                 PRIMARY  SECONDARY     BACKUP
-- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
45 12/20/2018 03:12:24 PM 01/02/2019 04:09:58 PM       4565       4025           
45 01/02/2019 04:09:58 PM 12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM        594       4025
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want to aggregate by `id` and the date part of `date_asn`?

```
select id, min(date_asn) as start_cycle, max(date_asn) as end_cycle,
       max(case when role = 'Primary' then custid end) as primary,
       max(case when role = 'Secondary' then custid end) as secondary,
       max(case when role = 'Backup' then custid end) as backup
from t
group by id, trunc(date_asn);
```

If you want to fill the `secondary` with the most recent non-`NULL` secondary:

```
select id, min(date_asn) as start_cycle, max(date_asn) as end_cycle,
       max(case when role = 'Primary' then custid end) as primary,
       lag(max(case when role = 'Secondary' then custid end) ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by min(date_asn)) as secondary,
       max(case when role = 'Backup' then custid end) as backup
from t
group by id, trunc(date_asn);
```